# Give default value to nested jsonb on Rails 4 /postgresql 9.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I wish to add a jsonb column (called per_deal_numbers) on my User table and preparing the migration

```
class AddInfoToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :per_deal_numbers, :jsonb, default: '{??????}'

  end
end
```

It will look like this for example for a user with a lot of deals already done:

```
user=(
id:1,
name:Eric,
age: 24,
per_deal_numbers: {
  deal1 : {"nb_of_shots"=>20, "nb_of_lost_guesses"=> 6 },
  deal10: {"nb_of_shots"=>13, "nb_of_lost_guessess"=> 4 },
  deal5: {"nb_of_shots"=>54, "nb_of_lost_guesses"=> 9 }
}
```

What I'd like is to tell in my migration: whenever you'll upsert a new entry for a deal the user has just taken part in, put for nb_of_shots and nb_of_lost_guesses values equal to 0

Should I provide for this in the migration or later in my rails app logic method of upsert ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but perhaps the answer helps anyone more.
The object key must be written in quotation marks.

Here's an example:

```
class CreateSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :settings do |t|
    t.jsonb :price_calculator, null: false, default: '{"formula": {"main_factor": 8, "city_factor": 7} }'
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```